# Crash-safe append() in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

After updating to iOS 14 Developer Beta my app began crashing. Mainly it happens on line `axis.entries.append(Double(f))` of the library which I use for creating charts. Here is the console output:

```
Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1200.2.19.2/swift/stdlib/public/core/UnsafePointer.swift, line 832

Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1200.2.19.2/swift/stdlib/public/core/UnsafePointer.swift, line 832
```

I don't believe I can fix this library, so I want a simple solution just to prevent my app from crashing. This line `axis.entries.append(Double(f))` is being called multiple times without crashing, so what I want to do is to perform this `append` if it won't crash my app and don't perform  `append` if it will. Is there a way to implement this?

I have tried putting this line inside `try` and `if`, but with no result.

Comment: You cannot “catch” a fatal error, therefore  it must be fixed in the library. What library is it? Is it open source?

Comment: Is your code run on the same thread? Arrays are not thread safe and therefore they can produce crashes if you use them from several threads simultaneously.

Comment: @MartinR It is github.com/danielgindi/Charts. I already opened an issue but I'm not sure if it will be fixed before iOS 14 release, so I am trying to find some way to deal with it.